# Format specifier int * warning message

Tags: c, pointers, format-specifiers

I wrote simple C program with scanf & printf like:

```
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int result = 7 - n;
    printf("%d", &result);
```

and got this warning message:

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2
>   has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
>         printf("%d", &result);

I dont understand why argument 2 has type int * instead of int? How can I solve this?

Comment: You just give it result, not address of result.

Comment: The warning message says all necessary. Read it and manual for `printf` before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is a integer variable. If you want to print its value then use `%d` format specifier & provide the argument as only `result` not `&result`.

This

```
printf("%d", &result);
```

replace with

```
printf("%d", result);
```

If you want to print the address of `result` variable then use `%p` format specifier.

```
printf("%p", &result); /* printing address */
```

**Edit :** `%p` format specifier needs an argument of  `void*` type.

So to print the address of `result` cast it as `void*`. for e.g

```
printf("%p", (void*)&result); /* explicitly type casting to void* means it works in all cases */
```

Thanks @ajay for pointing that, I forgot to add this point.

Comment: If you want to print the address of `result`, you should cast it to `void*` as `(void*)&result`.